# MySQL Trigger : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have problems creating triggers in MySQL 5.1.73
This is de syntax:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `discount2` 
BEFORE 
INSERT ON `order_item` 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE alumno INT;
DECLARE profesor INT;
DECLARE dto decimal(10,2);
SET @alumno := (SELECT user_id from `order` where `order`.id = NEW.order_id)
SET @profesor := (SELECT id_profesor from user where user.id = @alumno)
SET @dto := (SELECT descuento from descuentos
join user on descuentos.id_profesor = user.id
join producto on producto.familia=descuentos.familia
where producto.id = NEW.product_id and user.id = @profesor)

SET.NEW.descuento = SELECT CAST((((@dto)*(NEW.pvp))/100) AS DECIMAL(10,2))
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But there is some error...

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE alumno INT;
DECLARE profesor INT;
DECLARE dto decimal(10,2);
SET @alu' at line 5
```

Someone can help me, please?
Thanks u

Comment: An error on the create or an error on execution and what is the error code and message? Every statement has to be terminated with ; and you need a begin before your first declare and an end before the last $$.

Comment: In fact there are so many errors I have added as an answer.

Comment: I added the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this syntaxs but may not 'work'

```
drop trigger if exists discount2;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `discount2` 
BEFORE 
INSERT ON `order_stage` 
FOR EACH ROW 
begin
DECLARE alumno INT;
DECLARE profesor INT;
DECLARE dto decimal(10,2);
SET alumno = (SELECT user_id from `order` where `order`.id = NEW.order_id);
SET profesor = (SELECT id_profesor from user where user.id = alumno);
SET dto = (SELECT descuento from descuentos
join user on descuentos.id_profesor = user.id
join producto on producto.familia=descuentos.familia
where producto.id = NEW.product_id and user.id = profesor);

SET NEW.descuento = (SELECT CAST((((dto)*(NEW.pvp))/100) AS DECIMAL(10,2)));
end $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to create a `BEFORE INSERT` Trigger in MySQL is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT
   ON table_name FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   -- variable declarations

   -- trigger code

END;
```

If you want to **execute multiple statements** in your trigger, you should use **`BEGIN` and `END`.**

The Reason for using `DELIMITER $$` before and after the trigger declaration is to change the delimiter from `;` (default) to `$$`.

If you didn't change the `DELIMITER`, the first semicolon in your trigger code may be interpreted as the end of trigger declaration. Thus the code following may result in syntax errors.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `discount2` 
BEFORE 
INSERT ON `order_stage` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

   DECLARE alumno INT;
   DECLARE profesor INT;
   DECLARE dto decimal(10,2);
   SET alumno = (SELECT user_id from `order` where `order`.id = NEW.order_id);
   SET profesor = (SELECT id_profesor from user where user.id = alumno);
   SET dto = (SELECT descuento from descuentos
   join user on descuentos.id_profesor = user.id
   join producto on producto.familia=descuentos.familia
   where producto.id = NEW.product_id and user.id = profesor);

   SET NEW.descuento = (SELECT CAST((((dto)*(NEW.pvp))/100) AS DECIMAL(10,2)));
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Read More [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: Where does this differ from my (earlier) answer?

Comment: Almost same. But a little explanation is there

Comment: Would actually upvote if there were an explanation why the syntax error happens (and why therefore a different delimiter is needed aside the begin and end keywords).

Comment: @fancyPants Done

Comment: I'm still missing a sentence like "The first semi-colon would finish your trigger declaration. Therefore the next statement (DECLARE...)  fails with syntax error, because it's not allowed as statement outside of functions/procedures/triggers. That is why you have to change the delimiter...". Please provide answers with enough detail in the future and the upvotes will flow automatically. Anyway, have my upvote (for you're still "young" on this site)... ;-)

Comment: @fancyPants Yeah .. I will add it +1